# How do I print a webpage while expanding all toggle-div-header?

Tags: html, printing

I want to print this webpage https://www.sbi.co.in/portal/web/govt-banking/senior-citizens

The trouble is - I have to manually toggle each sub-section before printing. How can I make all subsections visible at a time and take complete printout?

Comment: got a working answer here https://superuser.com/questions/1281714/how-do-i-print-a-webpage-while-expanding-all-toggle-div-header

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been answered on [SU].

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be best off to save this page locally and then use basic HTML editing to make all divs visible. You would likely use something like style="display:block" in each of the divs.

You could also try to add this in Chrome inspector, but somehow Chrome needs to be convinced to load the page from cache, not from the web page again.